# Manage 2 Repositories in Maven Configurations

Tags: maven, repository, nexus

I have 2 nexus repositories, let say A and B.
When I build the project using Maven, I want to look for the missing dependencies (assuming I don't have cache) in A, and if not found try download them from nexus repository B.

how can I implement that in the best way?
I've tried mirrors, but they didn't work so far.

Comment: The best is to configure that in your repository manager...

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: Define the two repository in your repository manager and afterwards define a group repository which contains those two repos. The order give the order of fetch...Details can be read in the documentation of Nexus...

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by repo Manager? What is the needed pom configurations?

Comment: I mean by repo manager your nexus....cause you already have two repositories which from my point of view does not make sense but this is a different story...

Comment: @khmarbaise I have the same question and don't have the authority to ask for these changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add both repositories to the `settings.xml` or you set up a Nexus/Artifactory which proxies both repositories and point the mirror of your `settings.xml` to this Nexus/Artifactory.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I configure that behaviour in the setting.xml file exactly?

Comment: It is the standard behaviour of Maven. It goes through all defined repositories and looks for the artifact until it is found. For defining repository entries, see "repositories" in https://maven.apache.org/settings.html